# ImageMagick rotate animated gif glitches

Tags: imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

I'm using ImageMagick to rotate animated gifs. Simply:

`convert image.gif -rotate 32 -alpha set -background none output.gif`

Output:
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/108112/892631/ATp8mXXrDdSkCNu/sowa-test2.gif

Does anyone have a clue why output image is distorted this way and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the original image, I would suggest extracting each image, apply rotation, and then re-build the animated gif.

Example using the following gif:

[image: anim_none.gif]

```
convert anim_none.gif -scene 1 +adjoin tmp_%02d.gif
mogrify -rotate 32 -alpha set -background none tmp_*.gif
convert tmp_*.gif -loop 0 final.gif
```

[image: Rotated animated gif]

And note: quality is expected to degrade with rotation operations.

Comment: The thing is I must rotate dynamically each GIF because creating 360 GIFs for each of them doesn't make sense. We managed to remove glitches while exporting to PNG sequence and then using convert with `-delay` and `-loop` parameters. Also input PNGs cannot be optimized as it causes glitches again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from emcconville didn't quite work for me. Part of the issue may have been that my layers were transparent and so not all the same dimensions. However, using his solution as a base and then modifying it based on things I saw elsewhere, I was able to get my gif rotated:

```
convert my_gif.gif -background transparent \
        -virtual-pixel background -coalesce tmp_%02d.gif

mogrify -rotate -45 -background transparent -virtual-pixel background tmp_*.gif

convert tmp_*.gif -loop 0 my_gif_rotated.gif
```

Hopefully this helps others.